# Linear algebra: cross-product(proof of the property-Vector triple product)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading the book(Foundations of Game Engine Development Volume 1). I've studied the cross-product and there is one property connecting dot product with cross. `a×(b×c)= b(a•c)-c(a•b)`. During learning proof I saw one confusing to me thing[image]

It is written that this matrix looks almost like `baT(transposed)`. But on the previous page **a** and **b** were the vectors. How the author presents the multiplications of the two vectors as `matrix 3×3`.

I understand all logic(how to calculate that and so on), but the problem is how he represented the multiplication of `a=(ax,ay,az)` and `b=(bx,by,bz)` as `3×3 matrix`.

Comment: It’s a shorthand notation for an “outer product.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product?wprov=sfti1

Comment: The product of the $3\times 1$ matrix $\mathbf{b}$ and the $1\times 3$ matrix $\mathbf{a}^T$ (in that order) is a $3\times 3$ matrix.